# Xamarin android grid not scaling the cells proprely when an background image is added

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I'm trying to make a grid layout with 8 different boxes (2 colums*4 rows). Unfortunately whenever i try and load an image it bugs and loades an upscaled version of my image. Here is my code. Must note that is works just fine when i just load some writing in.

First it looks like this: 
[Without background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PBtz.png)

With the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:background="@drawable/garage">
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</GridLayout>
```

After i try adding the background image in one of the cells this is what i get: [Only one cell that takes up more space than the whole screen as it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3hWU.png)

Having the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:background="@drawable/garage">
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/spaceshuttle1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
</GridLayout>
```

What can i do so that image stays in it's cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to [TextView.onMeasure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)):

> The base class implementation of measure defaults to the background size, unless a larger size is allowed by the MeasureSpec. Subclasses should override onMeasure(int, int) to provide better measurements of their content.

So if your background image is quite big, `TextView` will be extended to the background's size.

To fix the problem, you can create your own TextView, and override the `onMeasure` Method:

```
public class MyTextView:TextView
{
    public MyTextView(Context c) : base(c)
    {
    }

    public MyTextView(Context c, IAttributeSet attr) : base(c, attr)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {

        int parentWidth=MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //set the size to the parent layout's cell's size.
        this.SetMeasuredDimension(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight / 4);
    }
}
```

And use the `MyTextView` in your layout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="4">
  <YourNameSpace.MyTextView
      android:layout_column="1"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@drawable/beautifulchristmas"
   />
  <TextView
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:background="@drawable/beautifulchristmas"/>
  ...
```